# Can I disable auto-aim when playing with a gamepad?

Tags: crysis

It's really obvious with the Automatic Grenade Launcher in Crysis Warhead. The AGL doesn't have an aim mode, so the view shouldn't change at all when you squeeze the left trigger. But if your reticle is near an enemy, the camera jerks in their direction.

I prefer the ergonomics of a gamepad and I don't want this crutch -- especially when it backfires and actually makes some shots more difficult. Is there a CVAR or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered at least two types of auto-aim in Crysis/Crysis Warhead. The first takes effect when switching into aim mode. It just jerks your reticle toward the nearest nearby target. The second type takes effect when firing. It's like a sort of magnetic attraction that dampens recoil drift -- very noticeable with automatic weapons.

Anyway, both types of auto-aim **can** be disabled via CVARs! Set `aim_assistAimEnabled` and `aim_assistTriggerEnabled` to `0`.

If you bought Crysis through Steam, add these to your launch options:

```
+aim_assistAimEnabled 0 +aim_assistTriggerEnabled 0
```